# how to spread work between multiple requests

Tags: jmeter

I need to test throughput running 8 JDBC requests by 4 threads.

For example, let's say I have 8 jdbc queries q1, q2... q8

If I specify 1 thread total, queries would be run one by one in that order q1,q2,q3..q8 and I get total time to run all 8 queries.

If I specify 4 threads, I need all 8 queries executed only 1 time but spread work across threads:

```
q1 thread 1
q2 thread 2
q3 thread 3
q4 thread 4
q5 thread 1 (or any thread who would be done processing its first query really)
q6 thread 2 (or any other)
q7 
q8
all done
```

I tried interleave with loop controller but I get either half of them executed, or 8 queries executed multiple times.

Basically, I need to measure throughput depending on the number of threads - how fast I can complete all 8 queries with 2,4,8 number of threads.

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is putting your queries into a CSV file and using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to parameterize the JDBC Request sampler:

[image]

Once done you should be able to define as many threads as you want under [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

[image]

So all the threads which you define will take the next value from the CSV file and run the respective query:

[image]

Comment: after spending a few hours with all kind of controllers, their combinations and such, this method is the only one that worked. Thanks Dmitri, you are Jmeter rockstar :) I  stumbled upon many of your other answers on SO that helped me a lot learning Jmeter